Mathematica will not compute this integral
I am trying to compute the following integral, but regardless of FullSimplify or Assumptions, Mathematica seems unable to compute it. I have already tried computing the indefinite version and evaluate that at the end points, but mathematica is unable to compute that one also. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
f[t_] := Exp[I c (t/2 + Sin[2 \[Omega] t]/(4 \[Omega]))]

tmp = Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, (2 \[Pi])/\[Omega]}] // FullSimplify



I do not think  Exp[Sin[t]] can be integrated. At least the indefinite one. If you have specific value for omega, then it can help.

Exp[Sin[t]] can be integrated (at least when provided bound values). Its one of those identities involving Series of bessel functions. However, the issue comes when introducing the t/2 term in the exponential. Without this the integral is easily computed. However I have no way to determine the result by hand when including this term

Yes, as I said, it cant for the indefinite case. But it can for definite case. sometimes definite version of same integrand can be solved. But your original integral is much more involved.

Ah sorry misread your initial comment. Still, this being a definite integral I would expect mathematica to try solving it, but it seems the notebook gives up quite quickly.

One easy way is:
$$\int_0^{\frac{2 \pi }{\omega }} e^{\frac{i c t}{2}+\frac{i c \sin (2 t \omega )}{4 \omega }} \, dt=\int_0^{\frac{2 \pi }{\omega }} e^{\frac{i c t}{2}} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{i c \sin (2
   t \omega )}{4 \omega }\right)^n}{n!} \, dt=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \int_0^{\frac{2 \pi }{\omega }} \frac{e^{\frac{i c t}{2}} \left(\frac{i c \sin (2 t \omega )}{4 \omega }\right)^n}{n!} \, dt$$
Then:
$Version
(*"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"*)

Sum[Integrate[E^((I c t)/2)*((I c Sin[2 t \[Omega]])/(4 \[Omega]))^n/n!, {t, 0, (
2*\[Pi])/\[Omega]}, 
Assumptions -> {c > 0, \[Omega] > 0, n >= 0}], {n, 0, 
Infinity}] // FullSimplify

(*analytic expression see below*)

$$\color{blue}{\int_0^{\frac{2 \pi }{\omega }} e^{\frac{i c t}{2}+\frac{i c \sin (2 t \omega )}{4 \omega }} \, dt=\\\frac{2 i \, _1F_2\left(1;1-\frac{c}{8 \omega },1+\frac{c}{8 \omega };-\frac{c^2}{64 \omega
   ^2}\right)}{c}-\frac{2 i e^{\frac{i c \pi }{\omega }} \, _1F_2\left(1;1-\frac{c}{8 \omega },1+\frac{c}{8 \omega };-\frac{c^2}{64 \omega ^2}\right)}{c}-\frac{2 i c \,
   _1F_2\left(1;\frac{3}{2}-\frac{c}{8 \omega },\frac{3}{2}+\frac{c}{8 \omega };-\frac{c^2}{64 \omega ^2}\right)}{c^2-16 \omega ^2}+\frac{2 i c e^{\frac{i c \pi }{\omega }} \,
   _1F_2\left(1;\frac{3}{2}-\frac{c}{8 \omega },\frac{3}{2}+\frac{c}{8 \omega };-\frac{c^2}{64 \omega ^2}\right)}{c^2-16 \omega ^2}}$$
Check:
f[c_, \[Omega]_] := NIntegrate[
E^((I c t)/2 + (I c Sin[2 t \[Omega]])/(4 \[Omega])), {t, 0, (
2*\[Pi])/\[Omega]}];

g[c_, \[Omega]_] := -((2 I (-1 + E^((
  I c \[Pi])/\[Omega])) (HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 - c/(
     8 \[Omega]), 1 + c/(8 \[Omega])}, -(c^2/(64 \[Omega]^2))] - (
  c^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {3/2 - c/(8 \[Omega]), 
     3/2 + c/(8 \[Omega])}, -(c^2/(64 \[Omega]^2))])/(
  c^2 - 16 \[Omega]^2)))/c);

{f[2, 2], g[2, 2] // N} // Chop
(*{0. + 2.10078 I, 0. + 2.10078 I}*)


Your result is an analytic expression, not a closed form expression (see Wiki for the definitions).

Using a substitution $x=2\omega t$ your integral can be reduced to the following function:
$$
f(a)=\int_0^{4\pi} \!dx\, e^{i a (x+\sin{x})}=\left(1+e^{2\pi a i}\right)\int_0^{2\pi} \!dx\, e^{i a \left(x+\sin{x}\right)},
$$
or in MA notation
f[a_] := NIntegrate[Exp[I * a * (x + Sin[x])], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]

where $a=\frac{c}{4\omega}$. It can be integrated as
g[a_] := Pi (1 + Exp[2 Pi I a]) * ((AngerJ[-a, a] - I WeberE[-a, a]) + 
    Exp[Pi I a] (AngerJ[a, a] + I WeberE[a, a]))

in terms of Anger and Weber functions. This follows directly from the definitions
$$
\mathbf{J}_\nu(z)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos (\nu\theta-z\sin\theta) \,d\theta,\\
\mathbf{E}_\nu(z)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \sin (\nu\theta-z\sin\theta) \,d\theta.
$$
MA seems to be unaware of these integrals.
Compare numerical and analytical results:
f[a_] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[I *a * (x + Sin[x])], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> Infinity, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
gr[1] = Plot[{Re[g[a]], Im[g[a]]}, {a, -2, 2}];
reF = Table[{a, Re[f[a]]}, {a, -2, 2, 0.1}];
imF = Table[{a, Im[f[a]]}, {a, -2, 2, 0.1}];
gr[2] = ListPlot[{reF, imF}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"];
Show[{gr[1], gr[2]}]


For integer parameter value a simplified formula exists:
f[a_?IntegerQ] := 4 Pi Exp[a*Pi*I] BesselJ[a, a]

as can be verified by MA for concrete values of a:
Integrate[Exp[3 I (x + Sin[x])], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
(* -4 Pi BesselJ[3, 3] *)


Look at (Entity["MathematicalFunction", "AngerJ"]["IntegralRepresentations"][[1]][\[Nu], z] // Activate) // TraditionalForm and (Entity["MathematicalFunction", "WeberE"]["IntegralRepresentations"][[1]][\[Nu], z] // Activate) // TraditionalForm

@BobHanlon Interesting, so MA "knows" these integral representations. It can also compute the integral for integer values of parameter, for instance, Integrate[Exp[3 I (x + Sin[x])], {x, 0, 4 Pi}] yields -4 Pi BesselJ[3, 3].

@yarchik thank you for instructive answer and comments!  :)

Your result for integer parameter value is an analytic expression, not a closed form expression (see Wiki for the definitions).
